# Files not available in docker volume: only recover old files

Tags: django, docker

EDIT 2

I change my docker-compose file using name volume for my app

So backup files are saved somewhere in my local desktop and I can retrieve backup from db and web containers

---

EDIT 1

if I remove 'shared' backup_volume backup files are available in container...
I used this shared volume to make backup files availables between web and db

---

I am a bit lost with my Django app configured with docker.
Stack: Django/Celery/Celery-beat/Gunicorn/Nginx/Postgresql/Docker

So I have an app with automatic Postgresql database backup using dbbackup (django app that make backup) app and Celery/Celery-beat (run command to make backup every hour for example).

I can build and run my project but something is going wrong with my backup files.
backup are done and store locally where expected.
But in my web container, I can only see old backup that are not more locally in my app (but probably in persistent folders)

so vene if I was able to remove this old files, problem will still be the same as new backup are not available in container

I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-preprod.yml down -v` to remove all volumes and rebuild container but doesn't change anything

So locally I have

```
- django-project
    - app
       - backup                               <- backup are made every hour and store in this bvackup folder
           - backup_2021-01-19-1600.psql
           - backup_2021-01-19-1700.psql
           - ...
       - manage.py
    - core
```

But when I 'jump' into my web container with docker exec -it web sh

```
- usr
    - src
       - app
           - backup
              - backup_2021-01-18-0800.psql    <- different backup files
              - backup_2021-01-18-0900.psql    <- different backup files
              - ...
           - manage.py
```

docker-compose-preprod.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        restart: always
        container_name: web
        build: 
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.preprod
        restart: always
        command: gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            #- ./app:/usr/src/app                 <- EDIT 2: change this line
            - app_volume:/usr/src/app             <- EDIT 2: with this line
            - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
            - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
            - backup_volume:/usr/src/app/backup
        expose:
            - 8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8000/"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 50
            
    redis:
        container_name: redis
        image: "redis:alpine"

    celery:
        container_name: celery
        build: 
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.preprod
        command: celery -A core worker -l info
        volumes:
            #- ./app:/usr/src/app                 <- EDIT 2: change this line
            - app_volume:/usr/src/app             <- EDIT 2: with this line
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_started
            web:
                condition: service_healthy
            redis:
                condition: service_started

    celery-beat:
        container_name: celery-beat
        build: 
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.preprod
        command: celery -A core beat -l info
        volumes:
            #- ./app:/usr/src/app                 <- EDIT 2: change this line
            - app_volume:/usr/src/app             <- EDIT 2: with this line
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_started
            web:
                condition: service_healthy
            redis:
                condition: service_started
            
    db:
        container_name: db
        image: postgres:12.0-alpine
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
            - app_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/backup     <- EDIT 2: change this line
        env_file:
            - ./.env.preprod.db
   
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        build: ./nginx
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
            - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
        ports:
            - 1340:80
        depends_on:
            web:
                condition: service_healthy

volumes:
    postgres_data:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:
    app_volume:                          <- EDIT 2: change this line
```